# MongoDB - Select Count with Group By & Order By

Tags: mongodb, select, count

I have a SQL Query that I am trying to convert into a MongoDB query.

```
SELECT `CrimeLSOACode`, 
COUNT(`CrimeType`) 
AS `value_occurrence` 
FROM `Crimes` 
WHERE `CrimeType` = "Vehicle crime" 
GROUP BY `CrimeType` 
ORDER BY `value_occurrence` 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The above query should return the CrimeLSOACode field that has the most fields with CrimeType set to = "Vehicle crime".

I have tried using SQL to Mongo mapping charts and converters but cannot figure out how to do similar actions in Mongo without order by.

Any help would be appreciated.

Sample document from collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cdef63ce59a9d4948e81d6b"), 
"CrimeID" : "298620fed5bf614b9adef619aa7aedd24f420f7ce7cafa65f16dde13da371706", 
"CrimeMonth" : "2018-05", 
"CrimeReportedIn" : "West Yorkshire Police", 
"CrimeFallsWithin" : "West Yorkshire Police", 
"CrimeLongitude" : NumberDecimal("-1.824938"), 
"CrimeLatitude" : NumberDecimal("53.639434"), 
"CrimeLocation" : "On or near Bridge Croft", "CrimeLSOACode" : "E01011149", 
"CrimeLSOAName" : "Kirklees 045B", "CrimeType" : "Violence and sexual offences", 
"CrimeLastOutcomeCategory" : "Under investigation", 
"CrimeContext" : "" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) will help you

```
db.crimes.aggregate([
  { $match: { CrimeType: "Violence and sexual offences" } },
  { $group: {
      _id: "$CrimeType",
      CrimeLSOACode: { $first: "$CrimeLSOACode" },
      value_occurrence: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0 } },
  { $sort: { value_occurrence: -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL` you can use in `SELECT` field only fields, which are grouping or aggregation function(`SUM`, `COUNT`, etc.). 
According [$collection.group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group)
it seems like this:

```
db.crimes.group(
   {
     key: { CrimeLSOACode: 1 },
     cond: { CrimeType : { $eq: "Vehicle crime" } },
     reduce: function( curr, result ) {
         result.value_occurrence++;
     },
     initial: { value_occurrence : 0 }
   }
)
```